# Регистрация домена украина

Tags: dns, домен

Подскажите как зарегистрировать доменное имя, какие хостеры не заберут просто деньги, а в замен ничего?

Answer (score 3):

Мои домены лежат на следующих сервисах:
http://www.ukraine.com.ua/
http://2domains.ru/
Качественные, за 5+ лет никаких вопросов и проблем нет.

Answer (score 2):

В Украине пользуюсь услугами регистратора [nic.ua](http://nic.ua)